# How to implements Marker Lazy Loading from URL in MapView overlay

Tags: android, android-mapview, itemizedoverlay, android-lazyloading

I have activity which can show overlay. This overlay have markers which gets from web.

How can I implements lazy loading from URL for this markers?

Thx, Igor

Comment: try to make you all data in background process  using http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Comment: could you please give me some sample with MapView and their markers?

Comment: do you know ?? http://developer.android.com/guide/tutorials/views/hello-mapview.html

Comment: Yes. i know this. I ask you about sample who shows how to implement overlay marker lazy load. For example, when MapView shows overlay the all of markers are same and calla "default marker". When i got real marker from URL i replace "default marker" with "real marker". Is it clear??

Comment: If no one answers before thursday, I will create a tutorial for this :D

Comment: ok, i wait for your tutorial). And if it works you got the bounty (+50)

Comment: @Sherif. Where is your tutorial???

Comment: @ihrupin I totally forgot about this! I will do it tonight

Comment: @Sherif. Bounty expires today. Hurry please

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you need to do is get create an AsyncTask to retrieve your data.  Once the async task executes and you have the data the UI thread will call onPostExecute(). In your onPostExecute() method you will add your data to your map view the same you would in the example android code.

Here's the a mostly complete example. You should be able to fill in the holes with this.

```
    public class SomeActivity extends MapActivity {
        private MapView mYourMapView;

        protected void onCreate(Bundle yourbundle){
          super.onCreate(yourbundle);
          setContentView(R.layout.yourcontentview);

          mYourMapView = (MapView)findViewById(R.id.yourmapviewid);

          GetYourDataTask task = new GetYourDataTask(mYourMapView);
          task.execute();
        }
     }

     public class GetYourDataTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{
           private MapView mView;
           private List<Items> mYourItemsFromInternetSource;

           public GetYourDataTask(MapView view){
              this.mView = view;
           }

           protected Void doInBackground(Void... params){
                .....get some data from internets
                mYourItemsfromInternetSoruce = something you got from internet;
                return null;
           }

           protected Void onPostExecute(){
                YourOverlay overlay = new YourOverlay(mYourItemsFromInterSource);
                mView.getOverlays().add(overlay);
           }
    }

    public YourOverlay extends ItemizedOverlay<OverlayItem>{
              private List<OverlayItem> mItems;
              public YourOverlay(List<Item> itemsFromInternet)[
                     super(boundCenterBottom(someContext.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.map_pin)));
                     //for your items create overlay items then
                     List<OverlayItem> createdItems = someConvertFunction(itemsFromInternet);
                     for(OverlayItem item: createdItems){
                          mItems.add(item);
                          populate();
                     }
               }
    }
```

Comment: I think you should call `populate()` after the for loop